# improve upon mapped lambdas in Python (pandas)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, lambda

I am digesting several csv files (each with one or more year of data) to categorize medical treatments into broad categories, while also keeping only a subset of the original information, and even aggregate up to a monthly number (by AR=year and month) of treatments per person (LopNr). Many treatments belong to different categories at the same time (multiple diagnosis codes are listed in the relevant column in the csv, thus I separate that field into a column of lists and categorize rows by any diagnosis codes belonging to a relevant range of ICD-9 codes).

I am using IOPro to save on memory, but I am still running into a segfault (still investigating). The text files are several GBs each, but this machine has 256 GB RAM. Either one of the packages is buggy, or I need a more memory efficient solution.

I am using versions pandas 0.16.2 np19py26_0, iopro 1.7.1 np19py27_p0, and python 2.7.10 0 under Linux.

So the original data would look something like this:

```
LopNr   AR INDATUMA DIAGNOS …
1     2007 20070812 C32 F17
1     2007 20070816     C36
```

And I hope to see aggregates like this:

```
LopNr   AR month tobacco …
1     2007     8       2
```

By the way, I would need Stata dta files in the end, but I go through cvs because pandas.DataFrame.to_stata seemed flaky in my experience, but maybe I am missing something there too.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import iopro
import numpy as np
from pandas import *

all_treatments  = DataFrame()
filelist = ['oppenvard20012005','oppenvard20062010','oppenvard2011','oppenvard2012','slutenvard1997','slutenvard2011','slutenvard2012','slutenvard19982004','slutenvard20052010']

tobacco = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'C30') and (x<'C40')) or ((x >= 'F17') and (x<'F18')))  for x in lst)
nutrition = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'D50') and (x<'D54')) or ((x >= 'E10') and (x<'E15')) or ((x >= 'E40') and (x<'E47')) or ((x >= 'E50') and (x<'E69')))  for x in lst)
mental = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'F') and (x<'G')) )  for x in lst)
alcohol = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'F10') and (x<'F11')) or ((x >= 'K70') and (x<'K71')))  for x in lst)
circulatory = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'I') and (x<'J')) )  for x in lst)
dental = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'K02') and (x<'K04')) )  for x in lst)
accident = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'V01') and (x<'X60')) )  for x in lst)
selfharm = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'X60') and (x<'X85')) )  for x in lst)
cancer = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'C') and (x<'D')) )  for x in lst)
endonutrimetab = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'E') and (x<'F')) )  for x in lst)
pregnancy = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'O') and (x<'P')) )  for x in lst)
other_stress = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'J00') and (x<'J48')) or ((x >= 'L20') and (x<'L66')) or ((x >= 'K20') and (x<'K60')) or ((x >= 'R') and (x<'S')) or ((x >= 'X86') and (x<'Z77')))  for x in lst)

for file in filelist:
    filename = 'PATH' + file +'.txt'
    adapter = iopro.text_adapter(filename,parser='csv',field_names=True,output='dataframe',delimiter='\t')
    treatments = adapter[['LopNr','AR','DIAGNOS','INDATUMA']][:]
    treatments['month'] = treatments['INDATUMA'] % 10000
    treatments['day'] = treatments['INDATUMA'] % 100
    treatments['month'] = (treatments['month']-treatments['day'])/100  
    del treatments['day']
    diagnoses = treatments['DIAGNOS'].str.split(' ')
    del treatments['DIAGNOS']
    treatments['tobacco'] = diagnoses.map(tobacco)
    treatments['nutrition'] = diagnoses.map(nutrition)
    treatments['mental'] = diagnoses.map(mental)
    treatments['alcohol'] = diagnoses.map(alcohol)
    treatments['circulatory'] = diagnoses.map(circulatory)
    treatments['dental'] = diagnoses.map(dental)
    treatments['accident'] = diagnoses.map(accident)
    treatments['selfharm'] = diagnoses.map(selfharm)
    treatments['cancer'] = diagnoses.map(cancer)
    treatments['endonutrimetab'] = diagnoses.map(endonutrimetab)
    treatments['pregnancy'] = diagnoses.map(pregnancy)
    treatments['other_stress'] = diagnoses.map(other_stress)
    all_treatments = all_treatments.append(treatments)
all_treatments = all_treatments.groupby(['LopNr','AR','month']).aggregate(np.count_nonzero) #.sum()
all_treatments = all_treatments.astype(int,copy=False,raise_on_error=False)
all_treatments.to_csv('PATH.csv')
```

Comment: You are doing a lot of range checking in your functions. You can simplify something like `(x >= 'C30') and (x < 'C40')` to `('C30' <= x < 'C40')`.

Comment: Also, something like `((x >= 'O') and (x < 'P'))` can simplify to `x.startswith('O')`.

Comment: Note that I could avoid the segfault by avoiding IOPro. Still, all other improvements in answers improved the code immensely.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

1. As noted above, you should simplify your lambda expressions for readability, possibly using `def`.

Example:

```
def tobacco(codes):
    return any( 'C30' <= x < 'C40' or
                'F17' <= x < 'F18'  for x in codes)
```

You can also vectorize these functions as follows:

```
def tobacco(codes_column):
    return [any('C30' <= code < 'C40' or
                'F17' <= code < 'F18'
                for code in codes) if codes else False
            for codes in codes_column]

diagnoses = all_treatments['DIAGNOS'].str.split(' ').tolist()
all_treatments['tobacco'] = tobacco(diagnoses)
```

2. You initialize `all_treatments` to a DataFrame, and then append to it.  This is very inefficient.  Try `all_treatments = list()`, and add `all_treatments = pd.concat(all_treatments, ignore_index=True)` outside the loop just before your `groupby`.  In addition, it should be `all_treatments.append(treatments)` (vs. `all_treatments = all_treatments.append(treatments)`)
3. To calculate the month for the purpose of grouping, you can use:

   `all_treatments['month'] = all_treatments.INDATUMA % 10000 // 100`
4. Lastly, instead of applying your lambda functions to each file once its read, try applying them to the `all_treatments` DataFrame instead.

p.s. You may also want to try `.sum()` on your `groupby` statement instead of `.aggregate(np.count_nonzero)`

Comment: This is great. Would you build the vectorized function differently with numba? Maybe not worth the effort for string functions over an array of lists?

Comment: I haven't used numba for strings, so I'm not sure how it would perform.

Comment: So if I simply @numba.jit before def, not much will change? Maybe. Here is the link though: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#using-numba

Comment: I am trying all this out, but so far I am fixing this bug:
`all_treatments = all_treatments.append(treatments)`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: It becomes None with the first attempt at append. It is an empty list before, as initiated.

Comment: Done, of course. Should be simply `all_treatments.append(treatments)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84415/discussion-between-alexander-and-laszlo).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to find a way to vectorize your solution. Using `map` and lambda functions is not efficient and doesn't make use of the speed-ups that make pandas so useful. It's hard to say for sure because you haven't posted sample data, but I think a good starting point would be to do

```
diagnoses = treatments['DIAGNOS'].str.split(expand=True)
```

The result will be a data frame with a column for each word (or element in the result of split). You can then do vectorized comparisons against the whole DataFrame. It might looks something like this:

```
between_c_vals = (diagnoses >= 'C30') & (diagnoses <= 'C40')
between_f_vals = (diagnoses >= 'F17') & (diagnoses <= 'F18')
treatment['tobacco'] = (between_c_vals | between_f_vals).any(axis=1)
```

This should be hundreds of times faster than using `.map` which uses loops in Python. Note that the bit operators `&` and `|` can be used to perform set logic on Boolean vectors and matrices (or DataFrames). 
If you showed an example of `treatment['DIAGNOS']` I could maybe help more. One thing to be careful of is `NaN` values when doing comparisons as comparing `NaN` to anything always return `False` but I think it should be fine here is it won't return any unwanted True values.

Comment: Is it efficient to split the column if most new columns would be missing (NaN)? I think that would imply as many new columns as the longest DIAGNOS list was, while most other row have only a few DIAGNOS listed. Won't the new columns blow out of memory? I appreciate the principle of vectorization otherwise.

Comment: Well it might do, I'm not sure how memory would be handled in that case (You have 256 GB though?). Perhaps Pandas would handle it intelligently. As I said, it was hard for me to say as you haven't posted sample data and so I don't know the structure of it. Still though, I think it's a much preferable approach. If memory was problem you could do it in chunks. I think it will still be hundreds of times faster.