# pandas str.split with .tolist() produced a float?

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, split

I have a hard time bug fixing my code which worked fine in testing on a small subset of the entire data. I could double check types to be sure, but the error message is already informative enough: The list I made ended up being a float. But how?

The last three lines which ran:

```
diagnoses = all_treatments['DIAGNOS'].str.split(' ').tolist()
all_treatments = all_treatments.drop(['DIAGNOS','INDATUMA','date'], axis=1)
all_treatments['tobacco'] = tobacco(diagnoses)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "treatments2_noiopro.py", line 97, in <module>
   all_treatments['tobacco'] = tobacco(diagnoses)
 File "treatments2_noiopro.py", line 13, in tobacco
   for codes in codes_column]
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

FWIW, the function itself is:

```
def tobacco(codes_column):
    return [any('C30' <= code < 'C40' or 
                'F17' <= code <'F18'
                for code in codes) if codes else False
            for codes in codes_column]
```

I am using versions pandas 0.16.2 np19py26_0, iopro 1.7.1 np19py27_p0, and python 2.7.10 0 under Linux.

Comment: `for codes in codes_column` iterates over the elements from what .tolist returns` `for code in codes` is trying to iterate over a float in that list

Comment: So this function is supposed to work with a Series of lists. It did work exactly that way in testing. .tolist() produced a list for each element of the new Series from a Series of strings. You mean one element in the new Series is not a list but a float?

Comment: Make an explicit loop and print each code, it will be a lot easier to find the culprit

Answer (score 1):

You can use str.split on the series and apply a function to the result:

```
def tobacco(codes):
    return any(['C30' <= code < 'C40' or 'F17' <= code <'F18' for code in codes])

data = [('C35 C50'), ('C36'), ('C37'), ('C50 C51'), ('F1 F2'), ('F17'), ('F3 F17'), ('')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['DIAGNOS'])
```

---

```
df

    DIAGNOS
0   C35 C50
1   C36
2   C37
3   C50 C51
4   F1 F2
5   F17
6   F3 F17
7
```

---

```
df.DIAGNOS.str.split(' ').apply(tobacco)

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False
dtype: bool
```

---

*edit:*

Seems like using str.contains is significantly faster than both methods.

```
tobacco_codes = '|'.join(["C{}".format(i) for i in range(30, 40)] + ["F17"])

data = [('C35 C50'), ('C36'), ('C37'), ('C50 C51'), ('F1 F2'), ('F17'), ('F3 F17'), ('C3')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['DIAGNOS'])

df.DIAGNOS.str.contains(tobacco_codes)
```

Comment: Is apply as efficient as this "vectorized" function definition? I received this suggestion to avoid mapping, supposedly doing loops of my lambda functions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31638239/938408

Comment: Would the latest recommendation avoid this problem? I wonder why this is not a problem in my small-data testing: 
`File "treatments3_noiopro.py", line 81, in <module>
   all_treatments['tobacco'] = diagnoses.apply(tobacco)`
 `File "/home/seidav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2060, in apply
   mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)`
 `File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 1061, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:58435)`
 `File "treatments3_noiopro.py", line 11, in tobacco
   for code in codes])` `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: Most likely you have an entry that is not a string in the series.

Answer (score -1):

I guess diagnoses is a generator and since you drop something in line 2 of your code this changes the generator. I can't test anything right now, but let me know if it works when commenting line 2 of your code.

Comment: Ah, so `diagnoses` is not a fixed new Series, only a reference? I am behind with generators. OK, let me try what you suggested.

Comment: I still get `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`